# adobe-flashplugin package is virtual

Tags: firefox, flash, plugins, adobe

Trying to install flash on Ubuntu Mate 16.04, I went to https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/adobe-flashplugin/ thinking I could find the package there.

Instead I got a cryptic message:
[image: isn't everything virtual]

What does this message mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to me like you were trying to install the 12.10 Quantal version. That release has been EOL for a very long time now. If you want the Adobe flash plugin for Ubuntu MATE 16.04, the easiest way to do it is:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-addons
```

Comment: This might have incidentally solved the problem, but the answer is not correct. `ubuntu-restricted-addons` pulls `flashplugin-installer` up to Ubuntu 16.04, not `adobe-flashplugin`. While the former is sufficient for Firefox, it's still not `adobe-flashplugin` which the OP tried to install. I think the correct solution would have been to [enable Canonical Partners](https://askubuntu.com/a/999009).

Answer (score 1):

A virtual package allows for a common ***name*** to be depended upon by other packages even though several things might provide that service/function.  There's more than one way in the package archive to install Adobe Flash and each package causes the virtual package to appear as installed.  Another example of such is `ubuntu-default-settings`.

In a different tool like Aptitude or Synaptic you'd be able to select the virtual package and choose one of the options that provides for the virtual package.  Frequently `flashplugin-installer` is what is actually needed these days but other routes *are* possible.  Previously there was only the one installer but not any more.