# I am trying to download Adobe Flash 10 for Ubuntu 16.04.03 - 64 bit OS

Tags: flash, adobe

It gives me an error message of Package "adobe-flashplugin"is virtual.  This is after finding it on https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/adobe-flashplugin/ and clicking the icon for "Available on the software centre".  This is all on Chromium Browser.  Tried it in Firefox too and it says it needs to be opened with AptURL.  When I use that to open it it returns the same error message as above.

Help???

Comment: have you tried https://askubuntu.com/a/797589/ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adobe-flashplugin package is virtual](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797577/adobe-flashplugin-package-is-virtual)

Comment: @N0rbert: No. The accepted answer to that question may give the impression to work, but `ubuntu-restricted-addons` pulls `flashplugin-installer` in 16.04, not `adobe-flashplugin` which is required for Chromium.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: I checked `apt-cache depends chromium-browser`, it really `Suggests: adobe-flashplugin`. So you are right.

Comment: @N0rbert: Thanks for retracting the close vote. I added a comment to the other answer.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorted.  I checked the box to allow cannonical partners.  That allowed me to add it as I was trying to from software centre.  reboot and job done.  Many thanks for the help

Comment: @user78235: Good. Then can you please accept my answer (by clicking the gray check mark to the left of the answer) so other visitors see that the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

`adobe-flashplugin` is available in the Canonical Partners repository, so you need to [enable Canonical Partners](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner).

P.S. It should be noted that the [apps.ubuntu.com](https://apps.ubuntu.com) site is severely outdated. Canonical Partners currently provides Adobe Flash 28, not 10, and it's Adobe Flash 28 you'll install when you click that button.

Answer (score -1):

If you need Flash I would recommend installing Google Chrome.

You can download it from [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html).

When you have downloaded it navigate to the download folder and type:

***sudo dpkg -i NameOfDownloadedFile.deb***

It will ask for your password and install Chrome.